# Send clikable url from java

Tags: java

I want to send clickable URL from java code to UI where it return type initially was String

```
@POST
@Path("/crd")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String isValid(SomeDTO SomeDTO)
        throws Exception {
      // business logic
      catch(Exceptioin e){
      return "notvalid"
   }
}
```

Now i want send to ui url along with text(like notvalid.Click below link  to 
 user guide)

```
   @POST
    @Path("/crd")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String isValid(SomeDTO SomeDTO)
            throws Exception {
          // business logic
          catch(Exceptioin e){
          return "notvalid"+url
       }
    }
```

- before i was notvalid 
  ---expected is notvalid.Cilck below link to user guide.

Comment: Your examples lack of context. You create a url from a rest service, as plain text. This url (something like http://test.com/do) seems to be used by a frontend somewhere. If you do "notvalid"+url , these will be an invalid url like "novalidhttp://test.com/do", so I'm confused about this request

Comment: /crd a rest call from front end and if it goes to exception i want to show in ui like "not valid" along with this i want give some use guide info link which is in world wide web like https://www.somewebsitename.com

Comment: Try using hateoas to send the resource URL in your response.

Comment: If it so, you should use http response code (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) for example HTTP code 400 Bad Request so client can handle this and redirect to proper page, which kind of ui framework (react, angular, etc.. ) do you use ?

Comment: using javascript + dojo framework

Comment: @PauloPedroso ,Here my rest call returning String, so can we use hateoas here,if everything goes fine i'm returning just "Success" , so is that work for hateoas?

Comment: You can build the object the way you want. Usually hateoas goes under a property named link but I believe you can go around this as well. The beauty of hateoas is it builds the URL for your controller method, no matter what it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
return "notvalid"+"<a href=\"https://somewebsiteinfoc/ target=\"_blank\">Click here</a> for more info";
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer, just putting a random line of code without an explanation is not an answer.

Comment: Code only answers aren't good answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. How does reading the question explain your code?

Comment: I did not meant that ,i added what i want i want in question along with the code right,i think you can understand